# Most efficient way of inserting in between a list?

Tags: python, list, list-manipulation

I am reading a file and building a list `a2`.
and I want to insert 3 lines to list `a2` from list `b` after first two items .

```
b = ["This is a line", "another line", "and another one"]
a2 = ['a1', 'a2', 'a3']

i = 0
for x, y in map(None, a2[0:2], a2):
    i = i + 1
    if x == y:
        continue
    else:
        for newLine in b:
            a2.insert(i-1, newLine)
            i = i+1
print a2
```

The above does give me expected result like `['a1', 'a2', 'This is a line', 'another line', 'and another one', 'a3']` but since I am going to build list out of huge text file and insert few lines in between I am thinking I have to make it more performance intuitive!

Comment: Do you actually need it as a list? Using iterators may be more efficient.

Comment: @jonrsharpe not really , I just want the most performance intuitive way to insert inbetween lines of a file.

Comment: That doesn't answer my question. Could you give a less abstract example of what you're actually trying to achieve?

Comment: Where does the 2 in `a2[0:2]` come from? The point is, that the simplest way to do this would be `a2[:2] + b + a2[2:]`, but it requires knowing these indices. Also, what do you want to do with `a2` after that? If you only access its elements sequentially (like writing back to file or some algorithms), writing a generator function would be a much faster choice, as it avoids building the whole list up front.

Comment: BTW: Which Python version? It's not 3.x (which I'd suggest you use), but one of the 2.x variants...

Comment: @san Insert should happen only after 2 positions? initially your list `a2` size is fixed or it may vary?

Comment: You have to tell more specific what you actually want to achieve. I suspect that you've added requirements that aren't really relevant. Fx indexing your sequence - is that required? If you tell us maybe there is a more efficient solution.

Comment: yes, this is an example and insert is supposed to happened after 2 position.

Comment: @san Is this just an example or is the insertion always after 2 position? Note that this makes a difference because the best solution differs depending on what assumtions one could make. A solution that assumes that insertion will always happen at position 2 may backfire if you later start to insert at a completely different position (fx at the end of the list).

Answer (score 4):

How about -

```
a2[2:2] = b
```

Demo -

```
>>> b = ["This is a line", "another line", "and another one"]
>>> a2 = ['a1', 'a2', 'a3']
>>> a2[2:2] = b
>>> a2
['a1', 'a2', 'This is a line', 'another line', 'and another one', 'a3']
```

---

Timing Information on some of the methods I know of (including the one posted by OP) -

```
def func1():
    b = ["This is a line", "another line", "and another one"]
    a2 = ['a1', 'a2', 'a3']
    i = 0
    for x, y in map(None, a2[0:2], a2):
        i = i + 1
        if x == y:
            continue
        else:
            for newLine in b:
                a2.insert(i-1, newLine)
                i = i+1
    return a2


def func2():
    b = ["This is a line", "another line", "and another one"]
    a2 = ['a1', 'a2', 'a3']
    a2 = a2[:2] + b + a2[2:]
    return a2

def func3():
    b = ["This is a line", "another line", "and another one"]
    a2 = ['a1', 'a2', 'a3']
    a2[2:2] = b
    return a2


import timeit

print timeit.timeit(func1,number=500000)
print timeit.timeit(func2,number=500000)
print timeit.timeit(func3,number=500000)
```

Result -

```
1.81288409233
0.621006011963
0.341125011444
```

---

Timing results of `a` having 100000 elements and `b` having 1000 elements -

```
def func1():
    global a2
    global b
    i = 0
    for x, y in map(None, a2[0:2], a2):
        i = i + 1
        if x == y:
            continue
        else:
            for newLine in b:
                a2.insert(i-1, newLine)
                i = i+1
            break
    return a2


def func2():
    global a2
    global b
    a2 = a2[:2] + b + a2[2:]
    return a2

def func3():
    global a2
    global b
    a2[2:2] = b
    return a2

def func4():
    global a2
    global b
    a2.reverse()
    b.reverse()
    for i in b:
        a2.insert(-2, i)
    return a2

import timeit

a2 = ['a1' for _ in range(100000)]
b = ['a2' for i in range(1000)]

print timeit.timeit(func1,number=10,setup = 'from __main__ import a2,b')
print timeit.timeit(func2,number=10,setup = 'from __main__ import a2,b')
print timeit.timeit(func3,number=10,setup = 'from __main__ import a2,b')
print timeit.timeit(func4,number=10,setup = 'from __main__ import a2,b')
```

Result -

```
1.00535297394
0.0210499763489
0.001296043396
0.0044310092926
```

Reference to the timing test - https://ideone.com/k4DANI

Comment: well, their will be multiple lines to insert.

Comment: b is list in above example , did you try it with your example in the latest code ?

Comment: @san Please take a look at latest answer with timing information.

Comment: Your solution is basically the same as in the question, just written in another way. Note according to the documentation `s.insert(i, x)` is the same as `s[i:i]=x`. It will hardly be more efficient, it will have to shift all subsequent element one step back in the list.

Comment: Did you even check the timing information posted above?

Comment: @AnandSKumar Yes, so what? Try to make `a` having 3000000 elements instead of 3. Note that he's talking about huge files.

Comment: @skyking check latest update, test with a2 having 100000 elements, please do not say baseless things without even trying.

Comment: @AnandSKumar Note that you had to reduce the number of runs that you had to perform. Note that if you increase the `a2` tenfold the three first solutions would increase about the same amount - despite you haven't changed the number of insertions. The last solution depends on the observation that insertion are done at the beginning of the list (which I'm sceptical about being a correct assumption - see the comments to the question).

Comment: @skyking I had to reduce the amount of runs because otherwise the online interpreter I am using (ideone.com) shows Timeout for more runs. Irrespective, for a single run when I increases `a2` size to `1000000` and `b` to `100000` . The method was still highly faster than other methods, and by much more percentage than for smaller inputs. Even in the above examples, when the input was increased, the method went from being 6 times faster than OP's method to near to 1000 times faster, I do not see where you are seeing that the method gets slower as the inputs increase.

Comment: @skyking Instead of baseless assumptions and accusations try coming with facts . Also, THE LAST SOLUTION IS NOT MINE , Mine is only `func3` , others are there for comparison of timings. Last solution is gsb-eng's . I am just doing time comparison. Atleast please read the post once (completely) before downvoting and commenting on it.

Comment: @AnandSKumar Yes, the asker has not provided any information on why one should assume that insertion always happens on position two. However it's true that by using list you will run into the problem of pushing the rest of the elements one step forward in the list. Note that reversing the list each time means that you will have to move all elements. Your solution will consequently need O(N) operations where N is the length of the array to be inserted into. Unless you can assume that N is small I will not consider it especially good performance.

Answer (score 0):

I'm giving this answer in a belief that your list `a2` is not a fixed size at the beginning and you've to insert all the values of `list b` into `list a2` **after** `index 1`.

Generally `list.insert()` works in this way, if `list l1` size is `n` (imagine that this n is hege) and if you try to add another huge `list l2` of values from the beginning lets say from position 2 `l1.insert(2, val)` this should move all the other elements of `list l1`  from `2 to n - 1` to next positions for every insert.

We can avoid this by inserting from the ending by `reversing` both the `l1` and `l2`.

Lets consider your lists `l1` , `l2` and we've to `insert` all the `l2` values into `l1` from the `index 2`.

```
>>> l1 = range(1, 10)
>>> l2 = range(10, 20)
>>> l1
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
>>> l2
[10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19]
```

After inserting the `l2` into `l1` with the below way.......

```
>>> i = 2
>>> for j in l2:
...     l1.insert(i, j)
...     i += 1
>>> l1
[1, 2, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
```

In the above way of inserting for every insert the values `3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9` in `l1` has been moved to next positions after proper `list.resize`. Assume that what will heppen if your 'l1' size is of `ten million` this movement of values becomes a overhead.

To avoid this data movement within the list for every insert, you can insert values from the end, in your case you've to reverse the list `l1` and `l2` and do `l1.insert(-2, l2.val)`

```
>>> l1
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
>>> l2
[10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19]
>>> l1.reverse()
>>> l2.reverse()
>>> l1
[9, 8, 7, 6, 5, 4, 3, 2, 1]
>>> l2
[19, 18, 17, 16, 15, 14, 13, 12, 11, 10]
>>> for i in l2:
...     l1.insert(-2, i)
...
```

After inserting you'll get this ..

```
>>> l1
[9, 8, 7, 6, 5, 4, 3, 19, 18, 17, 16, 15, 14, 13, 12, 11, 10, 2, 1]
```

If you observe the data movement happened in this way of `inserting`, only values `2, 1` has been moved all the time while inserting the values of `l2`.

You can simply reverse the `l1` to get the desired list of values.

```
>>> l1.reverse()
>>> l1
[1, 2, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
```

in this way we can avoid the most happening `data movement` in `list.insert()`.

Time Stats: https://ideone.com/owzWza

Note: This whole solution works well in your case but in case if you've insert some value at the `middle` of the `list` you've to think again for another best solution.

Comment: @AnandSKumar  In the question he has given a simple lists for inserting one to other from certain positions, if you try for those values only hardly you would see no difference in execution times, try with `millions` of values in both `list a2` and `list b` see the difference.

Comment: @AnandSKumar I'm not sure what you've tried but I've increased the `list lengths` to `10k` and here is the result https://ideone.com/owzWza

Comment: @AnandSKumar Imagine what would be the result if the `list length` goes to 'millions'.

Comment: @AnandSKumar Yes Slicing always gets advantage over other ways, but here he is talking about files and if the file size is `Huge` he is not supposed to get everything to memory, in that case he can easily reverse the `file` and `read` the file in efficient way and use my method to get this done.

Answer (score 0):

If you really want to do what you're telling in the question. The fastest solution (if the array you're inserting into grows large) would be to use a custom container class instead. It has been pointed out that reversed list would be faster, but reversing the list each time you insert an element (and reversing it again after) is also costly. Something like this:

```
class ReverseList:
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwds):
        self.revlist = list(*args, **kwds)
        self.revlist.reverse()

    def __getitem__(self, key):
        # if you need slicing you need to improve this:
        return self.revlist[-key] 

    def __setitem__(self, key, val):
        # if you need slicing you need to improve this:
        return self.revlist[-key] = val

    def insert(self, pos, val):
        self.revlist.insert(-pos, val)

    # etc
```